# npm package is not updating with npm install command

Tags: node.js, npm, versioning, package.json

I have an own npm package called `mypackage`, which is installed in over 50 repositories. I recently updated `mypackage` from version `1.1.0` to `1.2.0`. In the `package.json` file in all repositories is the line: `mypackage: "^1.0.12"`
When I clone the repository, everything works fine and `1.2.0` gets installed. 
When I run `npm install` in an existing local repository, where version `1.1.0` is installed, it remains at that version, even if I delete the `package-lock.json` and the `node_modules` folder before running `npm install`. I tried `npm cache clear --force` too, but same issue.


What am I doing wrong? I really don't want to update one line in 50+ package.json files.


Thank you in advance, Simon

Comment: Doesn't `^1.1.0` mean that the package can update to, say, `1.1.9` but not `1.2.0`? E.g., patch version only.

Comment: @VLAZ: if you write ^0.13.0, you want to update patch and minor releases: 0.13.1, 0.14.0 and so on. This says https://flaviocopes.com/package-json/